# EditText showError() popup location

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having an EditText at the bottom of my Activity.
Setting error message.
The problem is that:
Firstly error message appears under the keyboard layer (as it appears at the bottom of EditText),
so it is invisible.

[image]

Secondly, when I hide soft keyboard - the message remains on the same place of the screen and now points now onto the wrong field.

[image]

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    //validating email
                    if (!isEmailValid(editText) {
                        //  email is incorrect
                       editText.setError("Email is incorrect");
                    } else {
                        editText.setError(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Manifest:

```
   <activity android:name=".view.activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: especially your manifest activity tag

Comment: I experience similar issues. Consider switching to the new `TextInputLayout` field from the App Compat library. You then call `TextInputLayout.setError()` instead of on the `EditText`. Unfortunately you may fix this issue, but will be trading in for a bunch of new issues, but at least the new issues are being actively worked on.